# If else statement that generate correct sql statement

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi I'm creating a multiple search form where in it could detect if the field doesnt have any values and would still search if 1 or more fields has input. But i can't seem to generate the correct sql statement for this.

```
    <html>
          <head>
            <title>Search  Contacts</title>
          </head>
          <body>

            <h3>Search  Contact Details</h3>
            <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
              First Name:<br>
                  <input  type="text" name="fname">
              <br>Last Name:<br>
                  <input type="text" name="lname">
              <br>Email: <br>
                  <input type="text" name="email">
              <br>
              <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
        <?php
        $sfname = $_POST["fname"];
        $slname = $_POST["lname"];
        $semail = $_POST["email"];
        $servername = "xxx";
        $username = "xxx";
        $password = "xxx";
        $dbname = "xxx";

        // Create connection
        $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

        if(!empty($sfname) || !empty($slname) || !empty($semail)){

                $emailQueryPart = !empty($semail) ? "Email LIKE '%$semail%'" : "";
                $lastnameQueryPart = !empty($slname) ? "LastName LIKE '%$slname%'" : "";
                $firstnameQueryPart = !empty($sfname) ? "FirstName LIKE '%$sfname%'" : "";

                $arr = array($emailQueryPart, $lastnameQueryPart,$firstnameQueryPart);
        $needsAnd = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i] != "") {
            if ($needsAnd) {
                $sql .= " AND ";
            }

            $needsAnd = true;
            $sql .= " " . $arr[$i];
        }

    }           
            }else{
                echo "You must enter at least one value";
            }



    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Known Problems.
1. "Email" value doesnt show up even if i input a value, it only shows

```
"select * from Userlist where "
```

2. If i only input in the firstname AND shows early, im probably wrong on how i placed my if statement for adding the "AND"
sample result is

```
"select * from Userlist where AND FirstName LIKE '%test%' "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution :

```
    $emailQueryPart = ($_POST['email'] != "") ? "Email LIKE '%" . $_POST['email'] . "%'" : "";
    $lastnameQueryPart = ($_POST['lname'] != "") ? "LastName LIKE '%" . $_POST['lname'] . "%'" : "";
    $firstnameQueryPart = ($_POST['fname'] != "") ? "FirstName LIKE '%" . $_POST['fname'] . "%'" : "";

    $arr = array($emailQueryPart, $lastnameQueryPart, $firstnameQueryPart);

    $sql = "select * from Userlist where";
    $needsAnd = false;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($arr[$i] != "") {
            if ($needsAnd) {
                $sql .= " AND ";
            }

            $needsAnd = true;
            $sql .= " " . $arr[$i];
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "You must enter at least one value";
}

echo $sql;
```

Comment: the implode function suggested by pjw seems more elegant though :)

Comment: I have now added the actual querying code block from db and showing the values as a table but it seems it doesnt work...

Answer (score 3):

You can use the implode function to join the `$arr` values:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
$lname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lname');
$fname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fname');
$emailQueryPart = ($email) ? "Email LIKE '%{$email}%'" : null;
$lastnameQueryPart = ($lname) ? "LastName LIKE '%{$lname}%'" : null;
$firstnameQueryPart = ($fname != "") ? "FirstName LIKE '%{$fname}%'" : null;

$arr = array($emailQueryPart, $lastnameQueryPart, $firstnameQueryPart);

$sql = "select * from Userlist where ";
$sql .= implode(' AND ', array_filter($arr));
echo $sql;
```

Comment: If is useful, you could rate up the answer, I'd be glad too ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in functionality of arrays:

```
$queryParts = array();
if (!empty($fname)) { $queryParts[] = "FirstName LIKE '%$fname%'"; }
if (!empty($lname)) { $queryParts[] = "LastName LIKE '%$lname%'"; }
if (!empty($email)) { $queryParts[] = "Email LIKE '%$email%'"; }

if (!empty($queryParts)) {
    $sql = "select * from Userlist where (";
    $sql .= implode(") and (", $queryParts);
    $sql .= ");";
} else {
    // display error
}
```

The `array()` method creates an empty array, the `$queryParts[]` syntax appends to the end of said array, and the `implode` method puts the array elements together (see http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php).

Comment: I assumed the variables would already be extracted from $_POST and sanitized. Fixed the blank.

Comment: i have now posted all my code, to avoid confusion theres actually a $_POST, @pjw, should i remove everything starting from if(!empty($sfname) || !empty($slname) || !empty($semail)){

Comment: @Prix OP some how assigned POST values into $fname,$lname,$email.

Comment: Yes, my snippet was supposed to replace the code block originally shown, namely the whole `f(!empty($sfname) || ...) { ... }` block. I just saw that your variables are called `sfname,...`, while I used `fname,...`.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam when one doesn't post such information and claim they get no result from a form the first thing one assumes is that they are not properly reading the `$_POST`, hence why my quote, however I see that the OP has now updated his question with that information.